# Delete values from table

Tags: reactjs

My application has a select with different data and a table where i add the data from select. Here appears a problem: After adding all data from select in the table, and deleting data from table, when i select just one value from input and click save, the last values from table appear again, even i selected just one.

In this way i delete:

```js
  const handleDelete = name => {
    setData(data.filter(item => item.name !== name));
  };
```

How to solve this? link to my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-hamilton-go4m3

Comment: @keikai, could you help, please?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I found, that you don't update parent state in child *handleDelete*. You use newPlayer as a state for Table, but don't update it. Now it looks like this:

```
/* index.js
add new function handleDelete and change table properties*/

const handleDelete = name => {
  const updSaved = savedPlayer.filter(item => item !== name);
  setnewPlayer(searchPlayer(updSaved));
  setSavedPlayer(updSaved);
};
........

<MyTable newPlayer={newPlayer} deletePlayer={handleDelete} />
.......

/* MyTable.js
edit function handleDelete and change table class*/

const MyTable = ({ newPlayer, deletePlayer }) => {

.....

const handleDelete = name => {
  deletePlayer(name);
};
```

Now it works pretty much fine. But also, I mentioned an issue with your select input. It doesn't work right, check your *filter* logic for options.

Good luck!

**UPD**

Look closer to this line:

```
const finalListOfParticipants =
  teamPlayer === undefined ? newPlayer : newPlayer.concat(teamPlayer);
```

There are two different objects. Your newPlayer coming from your select menu, newPlayer.concat(teamPlayer); coming from preloaded data. And you have one button Delete. Which object do you want to clear onClick?
My solution is working with select menu and newPlayer list only.
If you want to work with both lists, you need to transfer all your logic to the parent component *SelectWithHiddenSelectedOptions*. MyTable is a child component. I can't imagine how I can explain it clearly.

Comment: here:`const handleChange = selectedItems => {
    setState(selectedItems);
  }; `? Could you show me, please?

Comment: Check my updated version. Also, you can try it here https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-bash-u3vbh

Comment: i checked, it works, but just with added values, but in case if i have already values in the table, i cant delete them, just added values. like here: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-kare-rb5vi

Comment: Of course, you can't. Because of your list of savedPlayer doesn't contain preloaded data. In your logic, you fill the table by preloaded data if you have it, if not - let's add it from select. You need to transfer all your table logic into parent element. Your logic is upsidedown now.

Comment: i don't know why the default data from table didn't appear  in the codesanbox first time, but, initialy i have default data in the table, like now, and if i want i can add new  items, and in the same time  i should have the delete functionality for all items from table. Could you confirm. please, if now the default data in the table appeared?

Comment: did you checked?

Comment: Yes, I have preloaded data. Check my UPD answer.